# Solidity - How to split the URL?

Tags: solidity, string

I have an ipfs URL stored in a variable named `string memory _uri` and I am setting it to this in the constructor: `"ipfs://QmPsG54TQRaeuqRexDXxd77E916zMugjsqmifH2QTvAmxr/{id}.json"` and I want to split this to 3 parts so I can ask for whichever token I want:

```
abi.encodePacked(
            "ipfs://QmPsG54TQRaeuqRexDXxd77E916zMugjsqmifH2QTvAmxr/",
            Strings.toString(_tokenId),
            ".json"
           )
```

How can I split the `_uri` programmatically so the `"ipfs://QmPsG54TQRaeuqRexDXxd77E916zMugjsqmifH2QTvAmxr/"` and `".json"` parts could also be dynamic?

PS: I also have a `setURI` function to change the URI. This is why I need it to be dynamic.

PS2: The full function to retreive the token by ID in ERC1155 contract:

```
function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(
            abi.encodePacked(
            "ipfs://QmPsG54TQRaeuqRexDXxd77E916zMugjsqmifH2QTvAmxr/",
            Strings.toString(_tokenId),
            ".json"
           )
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any easy way to do this in solidity. And if you are forced to do string manipulation on smartContracts you have probably made an error in your idea/design of the whole thing. It's expensive and such a thing is better left for some API to do.

However, you asked for help, so here is an example of a contract with two functions that together do exactly what you need (They replace {id} in URL to whatever token name you would like.

Hope this helps you.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
 
 
 contract ReplaceWord {

 
 function _stringReplace(string memory _URL, string memory _tokenID) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _stringBytes = bytes(_URL);
        uint count = _stringBytes.length -1; //Length of string

        bytes memory idByte = bytes("{i");
        bytes memory word;
        

        bytes memory result = new bytes(count);
        

  for(uint i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        word = bytes.concat(_stringBytes[i],_stringBytes[i+1] );
        
      
        if (keccak256(word) == keccak256(idByte)){

            bytes memory firstHalf = new bytes(count);
            bytes memory secondHalf = new bytes(count);
            (firstHalf,secondHalf)= _splitString(_stringBytes,i);
  
            result= abi.encodePacked(firstHalf,_tokenID,secondHalf);
            _stringBytes = result;
            return string(result);

        }
     

    }
      return string(result);
 }


 function _splitString(bytes memory _stringBytes, uint splitPoint) internal pure returns (bytes memory, bytes memory){

      uint lenght = _stringBytes.length;
      bytes memory firstHalf = new bytes(splitPoint);
      bytes memory secondHalf = new bytes(lenght-splitPoint-4);


      for(uint n = 0; n < splitPoint; n++) {
      firstHalf[n] = _stringBytes[n];
      }

        //Using 4 because the is the number of char in "{id}"
      for(uint x = 0; x < (lenght - splitPoint - 4); x++) {
      secondHalf[x] = _stringBytes[x + splitPoint + 4 ];
      }

      return (firstHalf, secondHalf);

 }


 }
```